# Protractor: Size of screen

Tags: javascript, protractor

I use this property to define the width and height's screen:

```
var width = 1280;
var height = 600;
browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
```

In the method onPrepare() but this code is functional for some tests, not for all of them. Why is that? I don't redefine the screen's size in my tests.

Regards,

Johnny

Edit :
My version of Node is 0.10.33 with Protactor 2.5.1 .

Protractor's conf :

```
// Fichier de configuration pour Angular

exports.config = {
    sauceUser: "",
    sauceKey: "",

    capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'name': 'Protractor Circle CI'
    },

    specs: ["src/Bg/*Bundle/Tests/Angular/*Test.js"],
    exclude: ['src/Bg/*Bundle/Tests/Angular/*AuthTest.js', 'src/Bg/*Bundle/Tests/Angular/*RapideTest.js'],

    baseUrl: "http://bluegrey.circle.dev:8080/app_ci.php",

    onPrepare: function() {
        browser.driver.get('http://bluegrey.circle.dev:8080/app_ci.php/fr_FR/login');

        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('user@evolunium.fr');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('userpass');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('_submit')).click();

        return browser.driver.wait(function() {
            return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
                return /dashboard/.test(url);
            });
        }, 600000);

        var width = 1280;
        var height = 600;
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
    },

    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        showColors: true,
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
    }
};
```

An example of test which works :

```
describe("Carrière > Centre d'interêt", function () {
    describe("Tests d'ajout et de suppression d'un centre d'interêt", function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            // on compte le nombre d'element
            elements = element.all(by.css('.bloc__defaut'));
            elements.count().then(function (nbElementP) {
                nbElement = nbElementP;
            });
        }, 60000);

        it('GET /app_ci.php/fr_FR/dashboard/career/interest', function () {

            browser.get('/app_ci.php/fr_FR/dashboard/career/interest');
        }, 60000);

        it("Ajout du centre d'interêt", function () {


            // On clique sur ajouter
            element(by.css('.btn-add-js')).click();

            // On remplit le formulaire
            browser.findElement(by.id('CentreInteret_intitule')).sendKeys('CentreInteret_intitule');
            element(by.css('.u-btn-inverse')).click();

            // on re-compte le nombre d'element
            expect(elements.count()).toEqual(nbElement+1);
        }, 60000);

        it("Suppression d'un centre d'interêt", function () {

            // On regarde si toutes les fenetres de suppressions sont cachés au début
            expect(element(by.css('.bloc__suppression')).isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();

            // On clique sur supprimer
            element(by.css('.u-btn-alert')).click();

            // On regarde si la fenetre de confirmation de suppression est présente
            expect(element(by.css('.bloc__suppression')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

            // On clique sur supprimer
            element(by.css('.btn-supprimer-js')).click();

            // On regarde si l'element est caché
            expect(element(by.css('.bloc__suppression')).isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();

        }, 60000);
    });
});
```

And a test which fails :

```
describe('Carrière > Experience Pro', function () {
    describe("Tests d'ajout et de suppression d'une experience pro", function () {
        beforeEach(function () {
            // on compte le nombre d'element
            elements = element.all(by.css('.bloc__defaut'));
            elements.count().then(function (nbElementP) {
                nbElement = nbElementP;
            });
        }, 60000);

        it('GET /app_ci.php/fr_FR/dashboard/career/professionalexperiences', function () {

            browser.get('/app_ci.php/fr_FR/dashboard/career/professionalexperiences');
        }, 60000);

        it('Vérification si lors du clique de la checkbox le champs date se désactive', function () {
            // On clique sur ajouter
            element(by.css('.btn-add-js')).click();

            // On regarde si par defaut les champs ne sont pas désactivés (= active)
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateFin_day')).getAttribute('disabled')).toBeFalsy();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateFin_month')).getAttribute('disabled')).toBeFalsy();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateFin_year')).getAttribute('disabled')).toBeFalsy();

            // On clique
            element(by.id('ExperiencePro_enPosteajout')).click();

            // On regarde si les champs sont desactivés
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateFin_day')).getAttribute('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateFin_month')).getAttribute('disabled')).toBeTruthy();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateFin_year')).getAttribute('disabled')).toBeTruthy();

            // On regarde s'ils se redésactive
            element(by.id('ExperiencePro_enPosteajout')).click();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateFin_day')).getAttribute('disabled')).toBeFalsy();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateFin_month')).getAttribute('disabled')).toBeFalsy();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateFin_year')).getAttribute('disabled')).toBeFalsy();
        }, 120000);

        it("Réglage du format de date", function () {


            // Format mois/année
            element(by.id('reglageDate-js')).click();
            element(by.id('ExperiencePro_formatDate_1')).click();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateDebut_day')).isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateDebut_month')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateDebut_year')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

            // Format année
            element(by.id('reglageDate-js')).click();
            element(by.id('ExperiencePro_formatDate_2')).click();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateDebut_day')).isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateDebut_month')).isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateDebut_year')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

            // Format année
            element(by.id('reglageDate-js')).click();
            element(by.id('ExperiencePro_formatDate_0')).click();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateDebut_day')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateDebut_month')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
            expect(element(by.id('ExperiencePro_dateDebut_year')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();


        }, 60000);

        it("Ajout de l'experience", function () {


            // On remplit le formulaire
            browser.findElement(protractor.By.css('#ExperiencePro_dateDebut_day option[value="1"]')).click();
            browser.findElement(protractor.By.css('#ExperiencePro_dateDebut_month option[value="12"]')).click();
            browser.findElement(protractor.By.css('#ExperiencePro_dateDebut_year option[value="2000"]')).click();
            element(by.id('ExperiencePro_enPosteajout')).click();
            element(by.id('reglageDate-js')).click();
            element(by.id('ExperiencePro_formatDate_0')).click();
            browser.findElement(by.id('ExperiencePro_poste-ajout')).sendKeys('ExperiencePro_poste');
            browser.findElement(by.id('ExperiencePro_entreprise')).sendKeys('ExperiencePro_entreprise');
            browser.findElement(by.id('ExperiencePro_ville')).sendKeys('ExperiencePro_ville');

            element(by.css('.u-btn-inverse')).click();

            // on re-compte le nombre d'element
            expect(elements.count()).toEqual(nbElement+1);
        }, 60000);

        it("Suppression d'une experience", function () {

            expect(element(by.css('.bloc__suppression')).isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();

            // On clique sur supprimer
            element(by.css('.u-btn-alert')).click();

            // On regarde si la fenetre de confirmation de suppression est présente
            expect(element(by.css('.bloc__suppression')).isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();

            // On clique sur supprimer
            element(by.css('.btn-supprimer-js')).click();

            // On regarde si la fenetre affirmant la suppression est apparue
            expect(element(by.css('.bloc__suppression')).isDisplayed()).toBeFalsy();

        }, 60000);
    });
});
```

Edit 2 :
It's maybe a viewport's problem instead of screen size's problem. I tried on Chrome, Firefox, Safari with SauceLabs and it's same problem.

Comment: Could you provide an example of a passing and failing spec? There must be something going on in those tests that cause the window size to change :\. Could you also provide your 1. Node Version 2. Protractor Version 3. Protractor config?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Hence, I edited my post !

Answer (score 3):

You are actually returning from the `onPrepare()` function even before the `setSize()` is called:

```
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.driver.get('http://bluegrey.circle.dev:8080/app_ci.php/fr_FR/login');

    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('user@evolunium.fr');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('userpass');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('_submit')).click();

    // HERE!!
    return browser.driver.wait(function() {
        return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
            return /dashboard/.test(url);
        });
    }, 600000);

    var width = 1280;
    var height = 600;
    browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
},
```

You should either remove the "return", or set the browser window size before it.

You can also return a promise returned by `setSize()` - in this case `protractor` would wait for the promise to be resolved before executing the tests:

```
return browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(width, height);
```

They now even have this "feature" [documented](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/827554148d2af8e3dc1fdeb4481bfb906a98d116):

> `onPrepare` can optionally return a promise, which Protractor will wait for before continuing execution. This can be used if the
>   preparation involves any asynchronous calls, e.g. interacting with the
>   browser. Otherwise Protractor cannot guarantee order of execution and
>   may start the tests before preparation finishes.

Comment: Well spotted, it's more logic but same problem. Thank you for the doc.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try controlling the set size via Chrome Options ?
You may remove all other declarations for set size.

`'browserName': 'chrome',
   'chromeOptions' : {
    args: ['--window-size=Width,Height']
   },`

Comment: Same problem, but thank you i didn't know this option

Answer (score 0):

It's ok with Mac OS X platform :

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'platform': 'OS X 10.11',
    'name': 'Protractor Circle CI'
},
```

But it's not a perfect solution, i wait your notice